# Why PHP parsed input data to _POST array

Tags: php, post

PHP 5.6.2

I have input script `curlTest.php`:

```
<?php
print_r(array($_GET, $_POST, file_get_contents('php://input')));
?>
```

And script what I run:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/curlTest.php';
$data = 'test-data';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

I have such output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [test-data] => 
        )

    [2] => test-data
)
```

Why php parsed my input data in _POST? But on another machine on PHP 5.2.6 i have another output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => test-data
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

setting `POSTFIELDS` automatically tells curl you're doing a POST.

post/get data is key:value pairs. You've provided (`$data`) what PHP is parsing as a key without a value, so you've got `$_POST['test-data'] = null`, basically. POST data is passed to the script via STDIN, which is why `php://input` shows you test-data.

Comment: But in php 5.6 if i add header

Comment: try `test-data=foo`. or even just `test-data=`. If that shows up in your 5.2 dumps, then you've found a way in which PHP's behavior has changed between the two versions.

Comment: But in php 5.6 if i`m add header `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data'));` _POST array will be empty, only `php://input`. If php v. 5.2 _POST array empty with or without this header

Comment: because multipart has a much different body structure than a standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form submission. you're basically messing with curl. curl isn't going to analyze the header overrides you're performing. if you set a multipart header, but then don't tell curl you're doing so, it'll continue on assuming it's a normal urlencoded form and submit as such

Comment: You are wright, if i try to post `test-data=foo` it will be parsed to _POST array and in php 5.2